# How to load a PartialView in a specific View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Suppose that in my folder `Dashboard` I have a `PartialView` called `_RightSidebar`, I need to include this `_PartialView` only in the `DashBoard`, so I'm looking for a way to load the `_RightSidebar` only when the user is inside a view of `Dashboard`.

Actually I load the `_RightSidebar` inside the `_Layout` but if I'm not in the `Dashboard` I'll get an error because the `_RightSidebar` is only a part of the `Dashboard` (I want avoid to create redundant code for each Dashboard view).

The same mechanism already exist for the `Section` but I cannot find anything similar to the `_PartialView`, someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Layout, just define an optional **section**, and then on Dashboard page, render the partial view within this section:

**Layout.cshtml**:

```
@RenderSection("RightSidebar", false);
@RenderBody()
```

**Dashboard.cshtml**

```
@page
@section RightSidebar {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_RightSidebar.cshtml")
}
```

// EDIT: Alternate answer by using Layout inheritance.

**BaseLayout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()    
</body>
</html>
```

**DashboardLayout.cshtml**

```
@{
  Layout = "BaseLayout.cshtml";
}

@await Html.Partial("_RightSidebar.cshtml")
@RenderBody()
```

**DefaultPage.cshtml**

```
@page
@{
  Layout = "BaseLayout.cshtml";
}
```

**DashboardPage.cshtml**

```
@page
@{
  Layout = "DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: So in each Dashboard View I must include this? This is ok, but if I have multiple Dashboard views could the logic be semplified?

Comment: Maybe layout inheritance could help you. Just create a BaseLayout and then a specific Layout (inherited from BaseLayout) just for all the Dashboards, and other pages will use the BaseLayout...

Comment: Could you please show an example? I'm a newbie of ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 0):

You could just load it into your `Dashboard.cshtml`Like this

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_RightSidebar.cshtml")
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Assuming you are using .net core 2.0 but I'm pretty sure the above also works in 1.0 as well

Comment: I need to load _RightSidebar outside the body, that's why I need to load in _Layout, but only when the user is on a Dashboard view...